# changing user password through the database

Tags: php, mysql, passwords

Hi I am trying to create a page where my users can change their password. When I type in the current password and try to change it, it seems to be not recognising the current password. I was wondering wether it was because I have used md5 and salt1 and salt2 on the password on another php file?

Here is my code, any help and advice would be much appreciated.

```
<?php
session_start();


require_once ("connect.php");
require_once 'functions/cleanstring.php';
require_once 'functions/encrypt.php';


$password = clean($db_server, $_POST['password']);
$newpassword = clean($db_server, $_POST['newpassword']);
$repeatnewpassword = clean($db_server, $_POST['repeatnewpassword']);


if ($_POST['submit'] == 'Change') {
    if ($password && $newpassword && $repeatnewpassword) {
        if ($newpassword == $repeatnewpassword) {
            if ($db_server) {

                mysqli_select_db($db_server, $db_database);
                $password = ($password);
                // check whether username exists 

                $query = "SELECT password FROM users WHERE password='$password'  AND         username='" . $_SESSION['username'] . "'";
                $result = mysqli_query($db_server, $query);

                if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                    $newpassword = salt($newpassword);
                    $query = "UPDATE `users` SET `password`='$newpassword' WHERE    `username`='" . $_SESSION['username'] . "'";

                    mysqli_query($db_server, $query) or
                            die("Insert failed. " . mysqli_error($db_server));
                    $message = "<strong>You've changed your password!</strong>";

                    //require_once("db_close.php");
                    // Process further here 
                } else {
                    $message = "Please type the correct current password!";
                }
                mysqli_free_result($result);
            } else {
                $message = "Error: could not connect to the database.";
            }
            //require_once("db_close.php"); 
        } else {
            $message = "The new password and the 'Repeat New Password' must match!";
        }
    } else {
        $message = "Fill all fields.";
    }
}
?>

<?php
include_once("templates/open.php");
?> 


<form action='changepassword.php' method='POST'> 
    Password: <input type='password' name='password'><br /> 
    New Password: <input type='password' name='newpassword'><br /> 
    Retype New Password: <input type="password" name="repeatnewpassword"><br/>
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Change'> 
    <input name='reset' type='reset' value='Reset'> 
</form>

<?php echo $message; ?>
<p><a href='login.php'>Go back</a></p>
<?php
require_once 'templates/close.php';
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your guess is likely to be true.  If you are storing hashed passwords then you will need to hash before doing the select.  It looks like the line with $password = ($password) should use the salt.  $password = salt($password).  This still looks wrong however.  Where are you storing the salt value?  If it's the same salt for every user, it's not effective.  The salt should be saved in the password table with the hashed password value so it can be used at a later time.

Comment: My Salt value is stored inside this php file named encrypt.php >> 
function encrypt($password){
 $salt1="egf";
 $salt2="7yh";
 $password = md5($salt . $password . $salt2);
 return $password;
}

I am creating an admin site, so only one user is needed, therefore as a single user operated site, i only have this one salt. In my database on cPanel, i have the long md5 hashed password showing to me.. the hashed version of the one the user types into the site. do i add my salt onto the front and end of that? 
sorry once again and thank you for your help

Comment: You should do the same procedure both when you select and save.  So use the same salt pattern.  One way to debug this is to print the hashed value you are using in the select to the screen before running the query.  Then you can manually compare that value to the one in the database.  If they are not matching, there is a problem in the conversion to the hashed format.  If they are matching, there is a problem in the query or in the way the query results are handled.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to `salt` the old plain-text password as entered by the user as well to do the check, because it's stored salted in the database.

Your code should be changed from:

```
$password = ($password);
```

to:

```
$password = salt($password);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you save your password using `md5()` , you should compare it with user input like :

```
if(md5($password) == $db_password) ...
```

OR

```
if(salt($password) == $db_password) ...
```

Comment: thankyou... but i added my salt1 function to the plain text password:
mysqli_select_db($db_server, $db_database); 
$password = salt1($password); 
and it is giving me the error 'call to undefined function salt1' 
this is my encrypt php file:
function encrypt($password){
 $salt="egf";
 //$salt2="7yh";
 $password = md5($salt . $password); // . $salt2);
 return $password;
}
I can't see the error... sorry to be confusing, and thank you!